# Joda Time, parse is not working

Tags: java, jodatime

I have this code, and don't know why it's not working

```
String dateTime = "Sun, 18 Apr 2004 02:32:43";
// Format for input
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss");
// Parsing the date
DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateTime);
// Format for output
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss");
// Printing the date
```

The **error** I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sun, 18 Apr 2004 02:32:43"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
    at com.jbd.WeirdCutEmails.test(WeirdCutEmails.java:69)
    at com.jbd.WeirdCutEmails.main(WeirdCutEmails.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Mind your `Locale` and if it supports "Sun" and "Apr".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inseted of `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss");`

Use `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");`

**kk --> hh**

Comment: H       hour of day (0~23)           number        0

Comment: k clockhour of day (1~24)      number        24

Comment: How is this the correct answer? Why would they want to use lower-case 'h' (12 hr clock). Why should this work and not the OP's code? Tom's comment from above is more likely to help.

Answer (score 4):

(credit to Tom for the suggestion)

This is most likely a `Locale` issue: if your default `Locale` does not recognise 'Sun' and 'Apr' then the `DateTimeFormatter` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

You can get around this by using [`withLocale(Locale locale)`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale-java.util.Locale-):

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss")
    .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Illustration:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testDefaultFormatterWontParseDifferentLocale() {
    //arrange
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss");

    //act
    dtf.parseDateTime("Sun, 18 Apr 2004 02:32:43"); //won't parse as expecting a String in Portuguese Locale
}

@Test
public void testFormatterWithSuppliedLocale() {
    //arrange
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat
                                .forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss")
                                .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

    //act
    DateTime actualDateTime = dtf.parseDateTime("Sun, 18 Apr 2004 02:32:43");

    //assert
    Assert.assertEquals(new DateTime(2004,4,18,2,32,43), actualDateTime);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en","US"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working..Try this.

```
String dateTime = "Sun, 18 Apr 2004 02:32:43";
// Format for input
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss");

// Parsing the date
System.out.println(dtf.parseDateTime(dateTime));

// Format for output
DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss");

// Printing the date
System.out.println(dtfOut.parseDateTime(dateTime));
```

Comment: And how is this supposed to fix OPs problem? You're using the same code for parsing the date.

Comment: This runs error, I am using inteelij IDEA, it`s maven project. Joda time import added in dependencies.

Comment: Any1 have a clue?

Comment: I turned Tom's comment into an answer

Comment: Thank you a lot. I`m going to check it out and tell u guys if it works for me.